# How to convert from std::tm to Windows::Foundation::DateTime

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I am trying to convert `std::tm` to `Windows::Foundation::DateTime` in Windows Runtime Component.

The only property in `Windows::Foundation::DateTime` is `UniversalTime` which is defined as:

> A 64-bit signed integer represents a point in time as the number of 100-nanosecond interval prior to or after midnight on January 1, 1601 (according to Gregorian Calendar)

Is there a way to do get this value in `std`? Or is there a standard way to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert you time to unix with `mktime`,
and then add magic number `116444736000000000ULL`:

```
    /* shift is difference between 1970-Jan-01 & 1601-Jan-01
    * in 100-nanosecond intervals */
    const uint64_t shift = 116444736000000000ULL; // (27111902 << 32) + 3577643008
```

from `boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp`

Comment: Thanks! I am look at the documentation on [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/), and I don't see it mentioning the return value of **mktime** is since when though. Is this always safe to use?

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t it is not explicity guaranteed on all system, but at least on windows and unix like OS it works as should, see for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246472(v=vs.60).aspx and of course you can use boost date_time that take care about platform independecy

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to derive this constant, but requires this [date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to serialize the two Gregorian dates:

```
#include "date.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using wticks = ratio_multiply<nano, ratio<100>>;
    constexpr duration<int64_t, wticks> t =
                          sys_days{jan/1/1970} - sys_days{jan/1/1601};
    static_assert(t.count() == 116444736000000000, "");
}
```

This requires C++14 to do at compile time.  In C++11, this can be done at run time (i.e. you can't declare `t` as `constexpr` or use it in a `static_assert` in C++11).  The [date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) has been ported to VS-2015, but `constexpr` is currently disabled for that platform.

**Update**

Here is code that converts a local `tm` into the number of 100-nanosecond units since January 1, 1601.  To figure out the local timezone of the computer, this [timezone library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) is needed.

```
#include "date.h"
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;

    // Concurrently initialize timezone database (as an optimization)
    thread{get_tzdb}.detach();

    // get an example local tm
    auto now = time(nullptr);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&now);

    // convert tm into a local time_point
    auto local_tp = local_days{year{tm.tm_year+1900}/(tm.tm_mon+1)/tm.tm_mday}
        + hours{tm.tm_hour} + minutes{tm.tm_min} + seconds{tm.tm_sec};

    // convert local time_point to UTC time_point
    auto tp = current_zone()->to_sys(local_tp);

    // Create handy types for dealing with 100-nanosecond units
    using wperiod = ratio_multiply<nano, ratio<100>>;
    using wticks  = duration<int64_t, wperiod>;

    // Get number of 100-nanosecond intervals since Jan 1, 1601 00:00:00 UTC
    auto t = wticks{tp - sys_days{jan/1/1601}};
    cout << t.count() << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
130925235970000000
```

Comment: Thanks! I am look at the documentation on [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/), and I don't see it mentioning the return value of **mktime** is since when though. Is this always safe use this constant?

Comment: `time_t`, the return of `mtkime`, is an unspecified encoding of a time point.  Typically it tracks Unix Time with a precision of seconds.  This is a count of non-leap seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC.  On some systems the count is held in a signed 32 bit integer, which gives it a range of 1901-12-13 20:45:52 to 2038-01-19 03:14:07.  64 bit architectures will usually make `time_t` a 64 bit signed integer, which extends its range practically forever.  Personally I avoid the C time API as much as possible as it is harder to work with it than completely ignore it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable insight! Unfortunately, if it not specified as such, I don't think it is a good idea to use `mktime` to covert to `DateTime` then.

Comment: What timezone is your `tm` in?

Comment: There is no guarantee for the timezone for `tm`. It is depending on where the customer is using the app.

Comment: Do you mean that the `tm` is always "local time"?

Comment: Yes, that's true~ Is there a better solution based on that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution which converts a local `tm` to the number of 100ns units since jan/1/1601.